# Answerable, a recommender of unanswered questions

Tags: app, questions, python, sort

### About

**Answerable** is a Python program that finds unanswered questions on **Stack Overflow** that you could be able to answer.

#### Background

At first I didn't know about the StackExchange API, so I planned to do it via web scraping. However, when I saw the amount of traffic that could mean, I decided to do a little research and found this site.

Web scraping has already been replaced by the API and RSS.

The reason to use the RSS feed instead of regular API requests is the quota. The API will be used only to recover the minimal information necessary to elaborate the learning model. Any thoughts on this are welcome.

#### Other sites

Supporting other StackExchange sites is not a priority right now.

#### License

It is free software under the MIT License.

#### Code

*Current Version*: **1.1**

https://github.com/MiguelMJ/Answerable

[Contributing guidelines](https://github.com/MiguelMJ/Answerable/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md)

[Changelog](https://github.com/MiguelMJ/Answerable/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md)

[Documentation](https://github.com/MiguelMJ/Answerable/wiki)

### Contact

- miguelmjvg@gmail.com
- https://miguelmj.github.io